# Preventing Hybris Backoffice Editor Popup from Closing After Saving Changes

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I'm working with SAP Hybris Backoffice, and I'm facing an issue with the behavior of an editor popup. Specifically, I have an editor area for a "User" type attribute called "userGroups," which uses the following editor configuration:

```
editor="com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.extendedmultireferenceeditor"
```

When I double-click the "userGroups" attribute, a popup appears, allowing me to make changes to the selected user group(s). However, the problem is that when I make changes and click the "Save" button in the popup, the popup automatically closes. This is the standard behavior for all editors in Backoffice popups.

What I want to achieve is to prevent the popup from closing after clicking "Save." Instead, I would like it to remain open, and the only way to close it should be by clicking the "X" (close) button within the popup.

I'm looking for guidance on how to customize this behavior. Is there an editor area parameter or a specific customization approach I can use within the Hybris Backoffice configuration to achieve this?